# How to get hash values from a website?

Tags: python, web-scraping, hash

I am a python newbie. I am currently doing basic web-scraping. On browsing through several GitHub projects, I found one that lets the user download an srt file.

Here's the doubt. Suppose the url is like this:

```
http://www.opensubtitles.org/en/subtitles/6528547/silicon-valley-the-lady-bs
```

How to get the random hash value `6528547`? On a side note, I request tips on how to get started working with APIs

Comment: Use [`urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urlsplit) to find the `path`.  On that string, do `.split('/')`.  Probably not perfect but pretty good.

Comment: If you want to be able to get that hash before you've visited that page, you can't ie you can't predict the hash value because it's an index id related to a specific thing, a movie in this case. If you want to get the hash when you already know the URL, you can do as @BrianCain suggested.

Comment: Here's the code that the project used.def get_hash(file_path):
    read_size = 64 * 1024
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
        data = f.read(read_size)
        f.seek(-read_size, os.SEEK_END)
        data += f.read(read_size)
    return hashlib.md5(data).hexdigest() <br> I think it is using some API to get the hashvalue

Comment: RohanMishra, do you want to fetch the hash from the already known url or you want to figure out hash to the unknown url?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have the url and just want to get the "hash", the easiest way to get the hash is to split it using '/' as the parameter and then getting the 5th element of the list returned.

```
url = "" #suppose you have the url here
hash = url.split('/')[5]
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nqu3d.png)